# Silent url rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm quite new to url rewriting and i need help about: i would like to redirect all the requests from `www.mydomain.com/fakefolder/Fake_Content` to `www.mydomain.com/realpage.php?parameter=Fake_Content`without the browser showing the real address in the bar. With the rules you can find below, i manage to accomplish the redirection task but i can't make the browser hide the real URL

```
 RewriteEngine on  
 RewriteRule ^fakefolder/([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*\_[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/realpage.php?parameter=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Just a note for the future - http://serverfault.com/ is a better place to ask these kinds of questions

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the browser to show the real URL, you are not rewriting or redirecting, you are proxying, which in `mod_rewrite` would be achieved via the highly-discouraged-in-the-official-documentation-so-don't-use-it `[P]` flag. Via the wonderful [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) wiki page, I suggest you instead use `mod_proxy`:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://other.example.com/$1 [P]

# is better expressed as..
ProxyPass / http://other.example.com/
```

Comment: For what i understand, ProxyPass doesn't use regular expressions